# Rejeitadas Flags a sinalizar comentários de agradecimento

Tags: debate, suporte, comentários, sinalização

De volta e meia fico um pouco baralhado sobre os comentários que são úteis e os que não são.

Também vejo algum contra-censo entre o que o *sistema* nos diz e aquilo que realmente acontece.

Quando estamos para comentar, podemos ler:

[image: Captura de Tela - placeholder nos comentários a respostas]

Ora, assumi que quando vejo comentários deste tipo:

[image: Captura de tela - comentários "não construtivos"]

Os mesmos enquadram-se na categoria "não construtiva":

[image: Captura de tela - sinalizar comentário]

Como tal, agi em conformidade e sinalizei os mesmos. Hoje reparo que foram rejeitados. Não só este exemplo como outros do género.

Não tenho interesse nenhum em andar a dar trabalho a ninguém (levantar Flag para ser rejeitada), nem tenho interesse nenhum em perder o meu tempo (levantar Flag para ser rejeitada), nem ando a tentar incrementar o meu contador de flags rejeitadas.

## Pergunta

Porque é que foram rejeitadas e como devo agir para estarmos em sintonia?

Comment: Ainda não tenho um posicionamento firme, mas creio que em geral, um comentário de agradecimento à pergunta parece ser bem recebido porque não polui muito a resposta e pode ajudar os visitantes a identificar que a resposta foi realmente útil. Além disso, considere que o brasileiro tende a ser mais condescendente. Obviamente, existem formas melhores de fazer isso, por exemplo: "+1 esta resposta me foi útil porque..." ou "-1 esta resposta é ruim porque...".

Comment: @utluiz Concordo +/- com o teu ponto de vista, mas nesse caso, tal como menciono na pergunta, a mensagem do `placeholder` deveria ser alterada para espelhar a correcta utilização dos comentários. Disse +/- porque pessoalmente e se calhar é como dizes, por ser Português de Portugal, qualquer comentário com "conversa" ou "obrigados" não é construtivo para o problema e só ocupa espaço.

Comment: @utluiz Já tive casos de passar por uma lista de comentários e pela persistência de ler até ao fim é que vi um utilizador a alertar para um bug na resposta. Ora, se não existissem tantos "Obrigados" e "conversa seca" pelo meio, o tópico estaria bem mais prático. Ou então existir um método de puxar comentários para cima (sei que existe o voto nos mesmos que os coloca no resumo quando a lista de comentários é demasiado grande para ser completamente apresentada).

Comment: Na verdade, não é exatamente o **meu** ponto de vista, é penas o que tenho observado. O que eu acho é que um comentário explicando porque a resposta foi boa ou ruim pode ajudar. Mas, se os comentários estiverem poluídos como o caso em que você citou, flag neles! E esperar que a comunidade aceite a flag.

Comment: @utluiz Qual a politica de moderação em relação a este assunto? Continuo a levantar _flags_ em relação a comentários de agradecimento e elas continuam a ser rejeitadas. Uma resposta por parte da equipa de moderação sobre a politica aplicada a este cenário ajudaria a evitar trabalhos por parte dos utilizadores do site.

Comment: Mais de dois anos depois, uma opinião: um meio-termo seria por a flag depois de algum tempo. Acho razoável usar a flag de "obsoleto" num agradecimento que tem, por exemplo, mais de um mês. O agradecimento não perde sua eficácia, pois acontece, e enquanto o post está "quente".e é visível publicamente, e sendo removido depois de algum tempo, evita o acúmulo desnecessário.

Answer (score 7):

Antes de mais nada, minha resposta não é a oficial, afinal sou apenas um dos moderadores e não falo por toda a comunidade.

Como você já sabe, nós não somos o SOEN. Acho que ainda estamos tentando estabelecer o que funciona melhor para nós.

Note que o texto de ajuda utiliza o termo *evitar*. Não é proibido agradecer.

Então o critério que tem sido adotado em geral é permitir comentários de agradecimento, desde que não haja exagero.

Enfim, não apagamos o agradecimento só porque é um agradecimento. Tentamos analisar o contexto  e verificar se o comentário se gera "ruído", como no caso de ter vários comentários.

Particularmente eu não tenho visto muitas sinalizações de comentários de agradecimento, então entendo que este não tem sido um problema para a maioria dos usuários.

Além disso, do meu ponto de vista (como já mencionei nos comentários), alguns comentários de agradecimento podem ajudar ao indicar *como* a resposta o ajudou o acrescentando algum detalhe.

No entanto, estou totalmente disposto a ouvir outros pontos de vista sobre o assunto.

Comment: No Stack-EN as perguntas com inúmeras vizualizações são bloqueadas para evitar uma enxurrada de "obrigados". Nunca vi isso acontecer aqui. Normalmente temos um único "Obrigado, isso foi útil", o que é bom porque às vezes os usuarios apenas marcam uma resposta como correta porque não apareceu nenhuma melhor.

Comment: @Andrey O bloqueio é para evitar "obrigado" como resposta, não comentário.

Comment: @bfavaretto Pensei que ele bloqueava comentários também.